# CSS code to negative indent the first word depending of its length

Tags: css

I have some html code which represents a paper sheet. In the h3 tag I have a title of a chapter. A chapter can have a number. The number is optional and it is inside a span with the class "number". I want all chapter title text start at the same distance from the edge of the page. It is set as a padding value 3cm. The problem is that I want all numbers to be before titles on "the padding area".
Example looks like this:

```
   1.2 Title of chapter

       some other text

 1.2.1 Some title of subsection

       All other lines beside numbers start at the same distance
       from the left side of page.
```

```html
<body>
<div style="padding:3cm">
<h3><span class="number">1.2 </span>Chapter title</h3>
</div>
</body>
```

Unfortunatyl I can't change the html code. My idea is to do some magic to place the number before chapter text relativly to it and to align the span right to the left side of text. Is it possible with only CSS?

Now I use javascript code and text-indent: -xxx ch; is added to h3. The problem is, that xxx must be calculated for each h3 tag. I hope it can be done with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done by CSS, take a look at this snippet:

```css
h3 {
  position: relative;
}
h3 > span.number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -3cm;
  text-align: right;
  width: 3cm;
  padding-right: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="padding:3cm">
    <h3><span class="number">1.2 </span>Chapter title</h3>
    <h3><span class="number">1.2.4.5 </span>Chapter title</h3>
    <h3><span class="number">1.3.1.2.4 </span>Chapter title</h3>
    <h3><span class="number">1 </span>Chapter title</h3>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this style for the `.number` class

```
.number {
  text-align: right;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}
```

See it here https://jsfiddle.net/6mpo5k2x/

Comment: Thank for the answer. I clicked point up but I have no reputation points and it is not visible. I accepted the next answer because h3 is positiononed relative and it collides with your code.